# Is there a way to calculate the rate constant of electrochemical cells?

Tags: electrochemistry, experimental-chemistry

I'm doing an experiment on temperature's influence on electrolysis of iron oxides and I need a way of measuring rate, preferably rate constant (k) or something similar. I've done some googling and there doesn't seem to be any calculations for rate constant for electrochemical cells or anything similar. The closest I've got was to use the Arrhenius equation and substitute the collision frequency/diffusion flux for the pre-exponential factor, but it doesn't consider voltage as an factor and I'm not sure if it's valid.

Can anyone tell me if electrochemical cells have a rate constant, and if so, how do I calculate it? If not, is there something similar?

Comment: Current times time equals coulombs of electricity. This must be related to the actual electrode reaction rates. You will have to do a voltage-rate- efficiency study and deconvolute the data.  This is done all the time in electroplating.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm assuming you're referring to Faraday's laws of electrolysis. I did think of using that by just measuring the current, but I haven't heard of voltage rate efficiency studies so I need to do some research into that.

Comment: Electrode half-reactions have rates, not cells. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tafel_equation

Comment: Note also rates of fast electrode reactions are controlled by ion diffusion rate and rates of slow ones are controlled by the rate of electron transfer.

Comment: The reaction rate in a cell depends mainly on the outer resistance of the electric circuit. If the outer resistance is high, the current delivered by the cell is tiny, and so is the reaction rate. If the outer resistance is small, or even equal to zero, the current is maximum, the cell is not a  cell anymore, as the outer voltage is zero. Then the reaction rate is maximum and depends on a lot of factors like the area of the plates, the distance between them and the concentration of the solutes.